# How to convert BitmapImage to WriteableBitmap in Universal application for windows 10?

Tags: converters, win-universal-app, bitmapimage, uwp-xaml

I am implementing a Universal Windows Application on Windows 10 using MVVM.
I have a file picker allowing me to choose an image. This image is displayed in an Image Control. The source of the Image Control is bound to a property in my view model. This property is a byte array. I need a converter to convert the BitmapImage in a Byte Array.
I have read lots of things but can't found something working.
I have found interesting stuff on https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/ 
but if i want to use this package i need a WriteableBitmap and not a BitmapImage.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the image to a WriteableBitmap object straight from the file.

```
var filePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
var result = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

if (result != null)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await result.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
        bmp.SetSource(stream);

        // show the image in the UI if you want.
        MyImage.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

This way you have the WriteableBitmap and you can use the WriteableBitmapEx library.

Comment: It's a very good workaround. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate !

Comment: Any idea how to achieve this without passing by the file picker ??